# GStreamer custom pipeline instead playbin

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to build a custom pipeline with GStreamer instead using playbin, so far I have this super basic setup:

```
filesrc -> decodebin -> streamsynchronizer -> xvimagesink
                                           -> autoaudiosink
```

(stream synchronizer is connected to both xvimagesink and autoautdiosink)

When I change the pipeline state to PLAYING all goes fine, both video and audio, when I want to pause the pipeline by setting its state to PAUSED and then to PLAYING again the video stays still while the audio continues playing as expected :/

I begin to loose my mind as the playbin element works well ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a streamsynchronizer. The name is confusing but it does not do what the name suggests. Something like the following should be enough:

```
filesrc location=test.mp4 ! decodebin name=dec  \
  dec. ! queue ! "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)" ! autovideosink \
  dec. ! queue ! audio/x-raw ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

As long as both sink elements have "sync=true" (which is the default) the video should display synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The following pipeline can pause and resume fine in my case:

```
filesrc location=test.mp4 ! decodebin name=dec      streamsynchronizer name=ss     dec.src_0 ! queue ! ss.sink_0     dec.src_1 ! queue ! ss.sink_1    ss.src_0 ! queue ! autovideosink filter-caps="video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)"   ss.src_1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

Note that I added a filter-caps property for autovideosink because in my case decodebin selects HW decoder outputting into NVMM memory. You would remove that if in your case it outputs video into system memory.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer for a similar problem - I've finally resolved it by building my app with flatpak and elementary 7.0 runtime, now everything works flawlessly, i dont even need to use streamsynchronizer or queue ...